# Get current category link

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm sure this is a basic question but I've been trying all sorts of solutions and nothing is working.

I have a single Wordpress post page, and I just want to make a link to that post's category. I can't find a way to get the current post's category's link, though. Ideas?

Edit:

This was the solution that seemed like it should work:

```
<?php 
$category = get_the_category();
$category_id = $category->cat_ID;
?>

<a class="button" href="<?php get_category_link( $category_id ); ?>">&larr; Back to Portfolio</a>
```

Comment: Show us some of the solutions you've tried.

Answer (score 2):

get_* functions are return functions. They don't actually print anything. Given your code example, all you should need is an echo statement:

```
<?php 
global $post;
$category = reset(get_the_category($post->ID));
$category_id = $category->cat_ID;
?>

<a class="button" href="<?php echo get_category_link( $category_id ); ?>">&larr; Back to Portfolio</a>
```

**ALTERNATIVE:** The best way of doing this would be to keep everything in your loop for reuse in single or archive views, combined with the use of [wp_get_post_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_categories). This is untested, but it should get you started with a general-use method of listing categories associated with a given post or set of posts:

```
<?php
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
    $cats = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
    if($cats) : foreach($cats as $cat) : $category = get_category($cat);
    ?>
    <a class="button" href="<?php echo get_category_link($category->cat_ID); ?>">&larr; <?php echo $category->name ?></a>
    <?php
    endforeach;endif;
endwhile;endif;
?>
```

Comment: Make sense, but still not working for some reason. The rendered page just has an empty href.

Comment: @user2990421 See the edited code. Since you're probably trying to get the category outside the Loop, and since `get_the_category` returns an array of categories, I've adjusted accordingly to render out the link of the first category associated with the current Post. The only stipulation is that this can only work if the POST (not Category archive) you are currently viewing has at least one category associated with it.

Comment: neither worked unfortunately. First option gave me the same empty href, the inside the loop one blanked out the page. Starting to think there might be something off with other parts of the wordpress files, though I don't know what it would be.

Comment: This solved my 4 weeks searching problem

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on the link [get_the_category()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category).

```
global $post;
$category = get_the_category($post->ID); 
if($category){
    echo '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id).'">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>';
}
```

Comment: How would I use this in the context of the code in my original post?